# Removing missing data in data step with do loop

Tags: sas

I am reading incomplete data in SAS and am having issues with skipping the missing values in a do loop.

My current code is:

```
data rcb_missing_LM;
 input blk @@;
 do trt=1,2,3;
  input y @@;
  if y=. then delete;
  else output;
 end;
cards;
1 47.2 . 49.4
2 . 56.6 53.6
;
```

The output I want to get is:

```
| obs | blk | trt | y    |
|-----|-----|-----|------|
| 1   | 1   | 1   | 47.2 |
| 2   | 1   | 3   | 49.4 |
| 3   | 2   | 2   | 56.6 |
| 4   | 2   | 3   | 53.6 |
```

Instead, I am getting the following:

```
| obs | blk  | trt | y    |
|-----|------|-----|------|
| 1   | 1.0  | 1   | 47.2 |
| 2   | 49.4 | 1   | 2.0  |
| 3   | 56.6 | 1   | 53.6 |
```

My best guess is that the DELETE command is throwing off the trt variable.

Can someone give me some guidance on how to fix this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are correct that the DELETE statement is the cause of the problem.  The DELETE statement stops the current iteration of the DATA step loop, and continues with the next iteration of the DATA step.  What you want to do is stop the current iteration of the DO loop you have coded, and continue with the next iteration of the DO loop. For that, you use the CONTINUE statement.  So you can code it as:

```
data rcb_missing_LM;
 input blk @;
 do trt=1,2,3;
  input y @;
  if y=. then continue;
  else output;
 end;
cards;
1 47.2 . 49.4
2 . 56.6 53.6
;
```

I also changed the input statements to end with a single @ rather than @@.  The double trailing @ holds the input record across iterations of the DATA step.  It doesn't cause harm in this case (other than a note about SAS going to the next line when it read past the end of an input line), but it's not needed.  On the first iteration of the DATA step, you read all of the values on the first input record.  With a single trailing @, on the second iteration of the DATA step, the pointer goes to the second input record automatically, and you read those values.

Answer (score 3):

You don't need the `DELETE` statement at all.  If you have an explicit `OUTPUT` statement then SAS does not output automatically at the end of the data step loop.

```
if y=. then ;
else output;
```

Or reverse the logic and you don't need the else statements.

```
if y ne . then output;
```